# Information:Your UI profile is not granted with permission to access this section. Please contact the administrator

Tags: kentico

after upgrading kentico 7 to 8 i am seeing "Information:Your UI profile is not granted with permission to access this section. Please contact the administrator." messgae while as soon as i start the application and login in Visual studio 2013.

Comment: I have already tired with assigning the current user to Global Administrator role which is shared in other suggested link.

Comment: This happened to me not a long time ago and the problem was with the "IIS cache". Can you try creating new IIS application and running your project from there?

Comment: I am running the application using IIS Express, which automatically start when you application run in visual studio 2013, not under the IIS

Answer (score 0):

Also try going to System -> Macros -> Resign macros, that can sometimes be the issue after upgrading.

Comment: Yes , I tried the same thing by updating the CMSHashStringSalt and fixed the macro issue/

Answer (score 0):

_i think issue was after upgrading we need to run the application which calls the 
UpgradeProcedure.Update(); function at application start up. file can be located under ~/App_Cdoe/UpgradeProcedur.cs.  Code will check for CMSDataVersion and update the database.

```
            string version = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetStringValue("CMSDataVersion");
            switch (version.ToLowerCSafe())
            {
                case "7.0":
                    using (var context = new CMSActionContext())
                    {
                        context.LogLicenseWarnings = false;

                        UpgradeApplication(Upgrade70To80, "8.0", "Upgrade_70_80.zip");
                    }
                    break;
            }
```